# Typescript import axios in VS2019 ASP.NET project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, axios, visual-studio-2019

I am struggling massivly with a very simple thing or it should be a simple thing.

i installed axios with the command

```
npm install axios
```

in the Package manager console of my project.
i then have a typescript where i want to use it,

i therefore use

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

this is my original typescript file

```
declare var Vue;

import axios from 'axios';

interface Product {
    Id: number;
    Code: string;
    Description: string;
    Ean: string;
}

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        id: 0,
        code: '',
        description: '',
        ean: ''
    },
    methods: {
        save: function (event) {
            console.log("Saving");
            axios.post('/Umbraco/Api/Products/Update',
                JSON.stringify({
                    Id: app.$data.id,
                    Code: app.$data.code,
                    Description: app.$data.description,
                    Ean: app.$data.ean
                }))
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("Saved");
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error");
                });
        }
    }
});

function initProduct(product: Product) {
    app.$data.id = product.Id;
    app.$data.code = product.Code;
    app.$data.description = product.Description;
    app.$data.ean = product.Ean;    
}
```

and then the "default" typescript compiler in VS2019 is generating following js file

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var axios_1 = require("axios");
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        id: 0,
        code: '',
        description: '',
        ean: ''
    },
    methods: {
        save: function (event) {
            console.log("Saving");
            axios_1.default.post('/Umbraco/Api/Products/Update', JSON.stringify({
                Id: app.$data.id,
                Code: app.$data.code,
                Description: app.$data.description,
                Ean: app.$data.ean
            }))
                .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Saved");
            })
                .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error");
            });
        }
    }
});
function initProduct(product) {
    app.$data.id = product.Id;
    app.$data.code = product.Code;
    app.$data.description = product.Description;
    app.$data.ean = product.Ean;
}
//# sourceMappingURL=EditProduct.js.map
```

Somehow i get an error on the webpage with this line
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

it says Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined.

what is up with all these types of javascript standards and ways to import require, ... it
i am loosing the sight in the forest of all the posibilities.

if i look on google, they always use the tsconfig.json file for settings, or its with .NET Core or its with something else, but i just want to have a basic thing.

Anyone can help me with it or does anyone have a good guide how to?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code for install;

```
npm i axios --global
```

and import axios when declare Vue;

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

and add it to your app;

```
app.use(axios)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use
`npm install --save axios`

Otherwise, the dependency will not be saved in the package.json. And also
`npm install --save @types/axios` for typescript support.

Comment: with these steps done, i have the same Uncaught ReferenceError in my browser

Answer (score 0):

> what is up with all these types of javascript standards and ways to
>   import require, ... it i am loosing the sight in the forest of all the
>   posibilities.

Yes this can be very confusing. Maybe you should start from the bottom and work your way up. Using typescript and axios already contains a lot of stuff which is going on in the background and without the propper knowledge this will get you lost. In the world of js most of the time there are many many things which play together to make the big picture.

**Here is what you could try**:

First you should make yourself familiar with javascript. Even/Especially if you want to use typescript in the long run, since its a superset of javascript. You can start out with the js-tutorial on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/default.asp).

If you dont have any experience with html and css you should also read it up here [html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

Then you could take a look at [babble](https://babeljs.io/) . It will transpile newer versions of javascript to older versions (since the newer versions are not supported by the browsers yet).

You should also check out a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).It will bundle all your sourcefiles for easy distribution.

Then you can check out [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and how to use it within your project and how to automate the usage.

I think from this point the way to go differs depending on where you want to go. So many things to discover like node, vue, react, axiom, graphql... and the list goes on and on.

---

What helped me alot is to start from the bottom. Simple javascript wihtout any thing else. Making myself familiar with it and work the things like webpack, babble, node etc. out just one by one. If you start with a setup where everything is already contained, you will not learn how each individual component works and how you should put them together.

Comment: Thx a lot for the explanation, but i actually know javascript syntax and coding very well once it is working. but i don't know how to configure it properly. i know of babble and webpack, and a linter like eslint and so on, once it is all configured properly. but the issue is that if i want to learn, they start a project from node, where a bunch of configuration is done for you, while i am using VS2019 with a ASP.NET project, these settings are without webpack and babel and linter and so on. but i need that, since i am using umbraco 8 Only working on .net 4.7.2 so i am kinda stuck between 2

Comment: Ah okay, so your main problem is to get a working setup with umbraco and VS2019 (not vscode, kinda overread that). I only use for vscode for webdevelopement so I can't tell you anything about the usage of VS2019. Maybe it would help to make one project for the backend with asp.net and one project without asp.net but with umbraco for the frontend?